# Docker File is not generating when I am creating my dev container on Github Codespaces

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I am trying to create a devcontainer having ubuntu but after creating the devcontainer it is only generating the devcontainer.json and the dockerfile is not generating , Why ?

I am selecting as follows -
1 - Add dev container Configuration files
2 - Create new Configuration
3 - Ubuntu
4 - jammy
5 - In additional I am selecting powershell
6 - Keep defaults

After this a folder named as .devcontainer is getting created with file named as devcontainer.json but the Dockerfile is not getting created within this folder with the devcontainer.json file. Why ?

Comment: This setup most likely uses an already existing image, so there is no need to create a `Dockerfile`. Can you post the contents of your `devcontainer.json`?

Comment: {
 "name": "Ubuntu",
 // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
 "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy",
 "features": {
  "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/powershell:1": {}
 }

 // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
 // "features": {},

 // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
 // "forwardPorts": [],

 // "postCreateCommand": "uname -a",

 // "customizations": {},

 // "remoteUser": "root"
}

Comment: The above is the code , Basically the uncommented code is  - "name": "Ubuntu",
 // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
 "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy",
 "features": {
  "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/powershell:1": {}
 }

Comment: I suggest you read the link that is already there. It explains how you can use your own `Dockerfile`. Also, for readability, post your json in your answer (edit it), within code fences. This way it is pretty unreadable.